# Dynamic package loading like java in golang

Tags: go

How Will I import package dynamically and invoke its method in golang like java reflection package, there are solutions of how to invoke method in the same file using golang reflection but what about invoking from different package

Comment: Yes. -buildmode=shared. Google for plugins. Not simple.

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing isn't dynamic package loading, it's just reflection. As long as the package is included in the binary and the types are exported, you can reference it the same way you can reference types in the same package.

Dynamic package loading is a different matter entirely; there's the new plugin support, which is still in its early stages, and not yet supported on all platforms. That's the closest you'll get.

Bear in mind that *Go is not Java*. Don't try to write Java in Go. It won't work. The platform, language, and standard library are very, very, *very* different between the two. Java can do dynamic class loading *because it has a class loader*. All types are dynamically loaded in Java. In Go, *nothing* is dynamically loaded; the Go compiler produces a native binary, there's nothing dynamic about it.

If you're trying to replicate something you're used to in Java, you're probably best served by rethinking your design entirely in a way that's more suitable to the technology you've chosen (Go), or to choose a technology more suited to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: That means it is not possible in golang, for the timings. as all other languages supports this to invoke other methods of different class in runtime using string name. whether it is java, node, php, c# or other languages .

Comment: All of the languages you listed are JIT languages that run in VMs. That's a very different prospect from Go, which generates a native binary with a minimal embedded runtime, which means it doesn't *need* a dynamic loader for its normal operation.

Comment: Thanks, but my purpose was to route the request to a controller page in runtime dynamically which is not possible till now in Go, I guess thanks anyway

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do dynamic routing at runtime; that's how the built-in router works as it is. That has nothing to do with dynamic class loading, though. Everything that might be used in a Go binary should be compiled into the Go binary.